# Proving that the vector field $F$ is conservative.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given : $F$ is a continuous vector field on the open connected set $D$ .

We need to prove :  If $\int_C F.dR $ is independent of the path within $D$ , then $F$ is conservative.

Proving the converse part was manageable , like we first say $F$ is conservative and then we prove that the value of the integral over a closed $C$ in $D$ is zero and hence conclude that the value of the integral is independent of the path , but how to tackle the above question ?

If we consider $\int_C F.dR $ is independent of the path , how can we conclude that $F$ is conservative ? Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to interpret 'connected' as 'pathwise connected'.

If the integral over a cycle is independent of the path chosen then it must be zero (you can make the cycle arbitrarily short, and the absolute value of the integral is bounded by the maximum of the continuous $|F|$ times the length of the path).

But if integrals over cycles are zero then integrals over arbitrary paths are only dependent on the end points. Now fix a point $a$ in $D$ and define the function $G$ at an arbitrary point $b$ as the integral of $F$ from $a$ to $b$ over any path that connects them.

Verify that $F$ is the gradient of $G$ by looking at paths that are parallel to the coordinate axes.